# Predicate in WatIn Find.By method

Tags: c#, watin

In Watin script I want to attach to another browser with the condition - "handle of new IE is not equal to handle of current IE", here is my code:

```
var hwnd = currentIE.hWnd;
var newIE= Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.By("hwnd", handle => !handle.Equals(hwnd)  ));
```

There is a warning from Visual Studio:

```
"suspicious comparison: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'string' and 'System.IntPtr'
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Watin is, but evidently `handle` and `hwnd` have different types (`string` and `IntPtr`), and there is no point to comparing them with `Equals`.

Whichever one is a string, you can try converting it to an `IntPtr`:

```
static IntPtr ParseIntPtr (string s)
{
    s = s.Replace ("0x", "");
    return (IntPtr) int.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
}
```

(I took the method [from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5cdbae55-2999-43ae-b75f-3f688609004f)).